# subtlety of self-defined function and its evaluation

Tags: functions, evaluation

I wrote a simple code as follows

```
f[x_,y_]:=NIntegrate[x+z,{z,0,1}];  
g[x_,y_]:=NIntegrate[y+z,{z,0,1}];  
VectorPlot[{f[x,y],g[x,y]},{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

then Mathematica shall give the right result of the vector field. But it also gives extra warning messages which puzzle me so much. They are of the same type as follows

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand x+z has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
```

It seems that `NIntegrare` cannot calculate an expression with some un-specific symbol.
But I just think that `VectorPlot`, just like other command, such as `Plot`, shall hold the expression of `NIntegrate` un-evaluate until it get the specific values of variables x and y. Such warning message shall not appear.
In fact, the command `DensityPlot` or `Plot` has no such problems. For example,

```
DensityPlot[{f[x,y],g[x,y]},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

Comment: change the definitions of `f` and `g` to include the `PatternTest`: i.e., `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: Check out http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502 and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)